# Remove empty line created from asp code in html

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic, web-config

If in a Classic ASP page I write:

```
<%pippa="Camilla"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

in the page source code I'll have a blank line before `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

How can I remove it?
I new that I can write all in a single line like this:

```
<%pippa="Camilla"%><!DOCTYPE html>
```

but seems quite weird in the rest of the code.
There is any way to solve it?
And if yes, is it possible to use a solution in the **web.config** ?

> What about using  **Dynamic Content Compression** ?

Comment: Dynamic Content Compression could help if it removes the white-space characters, but haven't tested it so my advice is give it a try and see how you get on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the cruxes of server side code generation, the ASP processor only processes ASP code *(code inside the in-line code blocks `<% %>`)*.

This means that any other HTML is left *"as is"* including special characters like carriage return and linefeed.

So when ASP processes your page it sees

```html
⏎
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

<sup>⏎ Denotes Carriage Return, LineFeed</sup>

So as you already state in the question the only way to avoid this is placing the in-line code block on the same line.

```html
<% pippa="Camilla" %><!DOCTYPE html>
```

The other approach is to break your HTML and your code assignment into different sections. I usually do this by placing my HTML inside it's own `Sub` / `Function` and pass or assign variables earlier in the page using an `Init()` Function, you still find yourself dealing with code like this though;

```vb
<%
Sub DisplayHTML()
%><!DOCTYPE html>
...
</html><% End Sub %>
```

Which isn't pretty, so I tend to ignore trailing new lines unless it's affecting the rendering of the page *(IE compatibility mode etc)*.

---

Another way of dealing with HTML inside your code is to build HTML templates to load the HTML and replace values defined by place-holders.

See [How to edit the html from ASP in a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36007779/692942)

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove it. When the code is run on the server, the code within the `<% %>` tags is executed and any output placed in their position. All other characters within the ASP source are left as they are. So the line break after the initial closing `%>` tag is left as it is.

The only way around it is the way that you have yourself suggested. ie:

`<%pippa="Camilla"%><!DOCTYPE html>`

Not pretty, but it works.